# How to get access to the sqlite db from an ec2 instance to my Jetbrain's Intellij IDEA Database Client

Tags: sqlite, intellij-idea, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get the access of the sqlite db which is present in my **EC2 instance**'s file system through the **Jetbrain's IntelliJ IDEA Database**.

I tried to connect other dbs like **postgres** and **mysql**, from them I just used the `**Use SSH tunnel**' and the added the **Host, User name, Port** with **Auth type OpenSSH**.

But in sqlite case there is not port they just create a file name ***db.sqlite3*** preset in ec2 filesystem. For my local file system i just add the path to the db but I don't know how to give path to the my sqlite DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [mount remote filesystem](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/sshfs) and then point IDE to this mounted folder and file. You can add mount command to 'Before connaction' tasks in Data source properties -> Options tab.